# How can one find a trustworthy mechanic?

Tags: repair

When shopping around for a new mechanic, are there any signs one can look for to see if the guy is a scam artist or if he is honest and knowledgeable?

Comment: This is going to generate a fair amount of opinion. Better that you ask such a question in chat over at [The Pitstop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop)

Answer (score 1):

Cartalk.com has a place where people post their recommended mechanics. I have found it useful. Here's the URL: http://www.cartalk.com/.

Comment: What about yelp?

Comment: Yelp = old organized crime protection racket, i.e. you pay me, and I won't write a bad review. I really don't like Yelp, but I guess that is a personal opinion.

Comment: I'm not a fan either, but Yelp has successfully shown in court more than once that they do not accept money for review changes, and they've started suing people who claim they do.

Comment: @barbecue, good to hear. I've heard advertisements on TV that pretty much imply that this, that, and the other service will write favorable reviews (web.com? on angieslist?, Amazon), obviously for a price. But this is way off topic. And I wasn't referring to Yelp accepting money; I was referring to the poster.

Comment: @BillOer gotcha